# Difference in a variable and function in C?

Tags: c, function, difference

I have just started reading Stpehen Prata's C Primer Plus (2013 edition) and I am stuck on a problem. I did not understand the difference in a "Variable" and a "Function". Do we have to define both in the header file?

Comment: Header files are for defining things that are external to the file being compiled.  That can be both variables and functions.

Comment: This website is not for asking just starting out questions. Try finding out some basic C language forums. There is actually no similarity between a variable and a function.

Comment: A function is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're at the beginning I'll try to make it as simple as possible:

A **variable** represents data.

A **function** operates on data.

For example:

```
int a;   // Variable
int b;   // Variable

// Function
int sum() {

    return a + b;
}
```

Headers files (`.h`) are just files that are like a summary of the relative `.c` file. Usually only functions and macros are defined inside a header file so you can keep a good level of [abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29) by hiding the implementation.

Comment: unless you are using a dll shared memory segment or memory mapped IO

Answer (score 0):

Header file is meant for defining **variables**, **macros**, **declaring**(**there is a difference between declaration and definition**) **prototype of functions**, etc.,, You will declare a function prototype in header file and define it in the actual c file.

For more you can refer 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm